# Numpy operation (3d kernel average on surrounding cells) on 3d Signal processing data

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, convolution

I'm working with a size 3d numpy array (10, 10, 10). I was wondering if there was a pythonic way to perform a kernel type (moving window) Weighted averaging operation on each point in my 3D numpy array? My data and first code attempt are shown below. I'm just trying to avoid reinventing the wheel if a numpy method exists.

To make things even more complicated, I was also not sure how to account for grid cells that are located at the edges (boundaries and corners, as they only have a partial of the window kernel around them). For these border cells, I would need weighted average as well. In other words, "for example", for the point located at the index (0, 0, 0) [which does not have a layer above), its resultant point after the kernel weighted averaging operating on it would need to be the weighted average of the available neighboring point from the kernel imposed on it. In this case, when we take average, to be fair, it should be divided on the available points of its neighbors, and not on the total number of the kernel size (3 * 5 * 5) as for the other points.

For the weighted_moving_average operation, the 8 immediate surrounding cells (6 points in the same layer as the signal source_point and two at the layer above & layer below) of the source_point should have a 70% (stronger weight) whereas the not_immediate sorounding cells (16) in the same layer as the source signal point should have 30% weights (weaker weights). Other points in the data present in the Kernel have weight of 0.1 (weakest signal) (as it can be seen in the Weights_of_3D_Kernel elements.

```
   import numpy as np

   np.random.seed(1)
   A = np.random.uniform(size=(10,10, 10))

   Weights_of_3D_Kernel = np.array([[

   [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]],

  [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.7, 1 , 0.7, 0.1],    # Signal source point is in this layer as denoted by weight=1
   [0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]],

  [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.5, 0.7 , 0.5, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
   [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
   ])
```

Comment: You tagged your problem `convolution`. Have you read https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) to accomplish this

```py
import scipy.ndimage

result = scipy.ndimage.convolve(A, weights=Weights_of_3D_Kernel, mode='constant')
norm = scipy.ndimage.convolve(np.ones_like(A), weights=np.ones_like(Weights_of_3D_Kernel) / Weights_of_3D_Kernel.size, mode='constant')
result = result / norm
```

where the `norm` variable is used to simulate truncating the kernel at the boundary.

Comment: Roy Smart: I tried your suggested method and I get the result (10, 10, 10), but its values seem way higher than what they are supposed to be. For instance if you look at the A numpy values, they are all less than 1, but the results values are all in the range of 8 and higher. Perhaps, I am not understanding, but how could a weighted average of a number less than 1 be so high? The idea is to get a sense of whats going on around the signal source point.

Comment: I think it's because the sum of your kernel is larger than 1. You can divide your kernel by its sum to normalize it